# java NullPointerException for GSON

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, gson, json-deserialization

I am getting a null pointer exception while using GSON library and trying to read a List (or array) via method call to process data-

The JSON object obtained externally is called Analytics (I defined as a class later) and has members like manufacturer (a string) and usage_statistics (a class I defined below). Analytics (data) looks like

```
{
    "manufacturer": "Motorola",
    "market_name": "Moto G4 Play",
    "codename": "harpia",
    "model": "Moto G Play",
    "usage_statistics": {
        "session_infos": [{
            "building_id": 17,
            "purchases": [{
                "item_id": 9,
                "item_category_id": 9,
                "cost": 69.98
            }, {
                "item_id": 81,
                "item_category_id": 6,
                "cost": 113.81
            }]
        }, {
            "building_id": 18,
            "purchases": [{
                "item_id": 180,
                "item_category_id": 0,
                "cost": 42.98
            }]
        }, {
            "building_id": 16,
            "purchases": [{
                "item_id": 78,
                "item_category_id": 3,
                "cost": 30.78
            }, {
                "item_id": 30,
                "item_category_id": 0,
                "cost": 101.77
            }, {
                "item_id": 171,
                "item_category_id": 6,
                "cost": 46.61
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

The design is

[usage_statistics is a class whose member session_infos is a list of session_info object. Each session_info object consists of a building id and a list of objects of type purchase. Each purchase object has a item_id, item_category_id and cost, all strings.]

The code that gives error on last line is

```
java.lang.reflect.Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<analytics>>(){}.getType();
list_analytics lcs = new list_analytics();
List<analytics> analytics = new Gson().fromJson(inline, collectionType);
for(analytics E : analytics) {
    System.out.println(E.getManf());//displays "Motorola"
    System.out.println(E.getsis());
    session_info_arr = (E.getsis()).getsession_infos();
    //...
}
```

(I am getting exception in the .getsession_infos() part. I am not sure why .getsession_infos() does not extract the list.)

The code:

```
public class analytics {
    private String manufacturer;
    private usage_statistics usage_statistics;

    public String getManf() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public usage_statistics getsis() {
        return usage_statistics;
    }
}

public class usage_statistics {
    private List<session_info> session_info_arr;

    public List<session_info> getsession_infos() {
        List<session_info> arr = new ArrayList<session_info>(Collections.<session_info>emptyList());
        arr = session_info_arr;
        return arr;
    }
}

public class session_info {
    private int id;
    private List<purchase> purchase_arr;

    public int getbid() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<purchase> getPurchase() {
        List<purchase> arr = new ArrayList<purchase>();
        arr = purchase_arr;
        return purchase_arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: add your stacktrace

Comment: @njzk2 How do I get full stack-trace? I removed the "limit console output" option but same output.

Comment: what output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need to see the stack trace to be able to help more.

In the mean time, I'm not sure why you have parentheses here:

```
session_info_arr = (E.getsis()).getsession_infos();
```

I think you meant this:

```
session_info_arr = E.getsis().getsession_infos();
```

Also, `getsession_infos` is poorly implemented. As written, it will create and throw away an empty ArrayList each time it's called:

```
public List<session_info> getsession_infos()
{
    List<session_info> arr = new ArrayList<session_info>(Collections.<session_info>emptyList());
    arr = session_info_arr;
    return arr;
}
```

I think you meant this instead:

```
public List<session_info> getsession_infos() {
    return session_info_arr;
}
```

`getPurchase` is implemented the same way:

```
public List<purchase> getPurchase() {
    List<purchase> arr = new ArrayList<purchase>();
    arr = purchase_arr;
    return purchase_arr;
}
```

Instead of:

```
public List<purchase> getPurchase() {
    return purchase_arr;
}
```

Comment: I did your edits, but it did not help. How do I get full stack trace. I removed the "limit console output" option but same output.